# Python -New DF column based on geometric series from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe that runs a geometric series on the other elements. This is what I tried

```
def get_choiceCost(numChances,init_cost,ratio):

#geometric series up to length specified by numChances

    g = sum([init_cost * 1/ ratio ** (n - 1) for n in range(1, numChances + 1)])
    return g
```

then i take my three arrays that I combine into a dataframe and then run my function and finally use it to create a new column in df.

```
numChances=[0,1,2,3]init_cost=[3,4,5]rat=[1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5]

products = np.array(np.meshgrid(numChances,init_cost,rat)).T.reshape(-1, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns= ["numChances","init_cost","rat"]);
```

act_cost= get_choiceCost(df["numChances"],df["init_cost"],df["rat"])

```
df['ev']=np.multiply((30-act_cost),.75)-np.multiply((18+act_cost),.25)
```

I get the following error

`Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

and turning init_cost into an integer gives me an error

```
cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

i tried also using map and running it over a list

```
  act_cost=np.array(list(map(lambda x,y,z: get_choiceCost(x,y,z), numChances,init_cost,rat)))
```

but this doesn't allow me to create my new "ev" columns

Any help with creating a new column based on a geometric series of the other columns would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question right, but I made a try:

```
 def get_choiceCost(numChances,init_cost,ratio):
     g = [sum([x/y**(n-1) for x,y,n in zip(init_cost,ratio,range(1, k + 1))]) for k in numChances.astype("int")]
     return g


 act_cost= get_choiceCost(df["numChances"],df["init_cost"],df["rat"])

 df['ev']=np.multiply(([30-x for x in act_cost]),.75)-np.multiply(([18+x for x in act_cost]),.25)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. however 
numChances=[1]
init_cost=[3,4,5]
ratio=[1]

the output should be [3,4,5] but comes out as [3,3,3]